# Unable to locate package while installing software

Tags: software-installation

Whenever I try to install (any) software using the terminal, the terminal is giving an output like:

```
E:Unable to locate package
```

Kindly help, as I am new to Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

You need to first update your packages list using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

so that apt knows from where it should download packages and then enter your password and then

```
sudo apt-get install <pacakge_name>
```